# Security problem in the application I developed with Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, security, web, next.js

I'm building a web builder using Nexjs. Like this (https://webflow.com/).
Everything is very good. However, if the save page as is called, users can download the editor part. How can I prevent this? How do editor applications like Webflow achieve this?